# set More Alarm in Android?

Tags: android

I use the following code to create alarm.

```
String strDateTime=strDate+" "+strTime;             
            DateFormat dfm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");              
            Date alarmTime = null;
            try {
                alarmTime = dfm.parse(strDateTime);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            long setAlarmTime=alarmTime.getTime();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmService.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            //set time and get the Intent 
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setAlarmTime, pendingIntent);
```

If i set more than one alarm the last one will be executed.How can i add more alarm time in android?

Answer (score 1):

Try to give every of your `Intent` (myIntent in code) some random data (via `setDat`a call) on every `AlarmManager.set` call

`AlaramManager` resets the alarm, previously set for the same `PendingIntent` (and yours PendingIntents are always the same)